# problem embedding matplotlib graph in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to embed an animation graph into my GUI, however, whenever I try what i've seen according to tutorials regarding the use of canvas, I get a blank tkinter screen. 
No errors, nothing.

However, when I use plt.show, it works fine but its not confined to the GUI. Which is the problem.

Its probably a quick fix, but this is what I have.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
class popupWindowOscil(tk.Frame):

  def __init__(self,master,ser):

    OscilTop= self.OscilTop= Toplevel(master)
    tk.Frame.__init__(self)
    self.ser = ser   
    self.fig = plt.figure()
    self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

    self.xs = []
    self.ys = []
    self.xval =0
    self.OscilLoop()


  def OscilLoop(self):

    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.Oscilliscope, fargs=(self.xs, self.ys))
    #self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self)
    #self.canvas.draw()
    #self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    plt.show()
    return

# The function that creates the values for the plot.
  def Oscilliscope(self,i,xs,ys):

    tryagain =1
    while tryagain == 1:
        try:
            reading = self.ser.readline().decode()
            tryagain = 0
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            pass
    Incominglist = str(reading).split(",")
    try:
        numbers = [float(x) for x in Incominglist]
    except ValueError:
        print ('Failure during string decode, Restart and Try again')
        return
    # Add x and y to lists
    self.ys.extend(numbers)

    for val in range(len(Incominglist)):
        if  self.xval == 0 and val ==0:
            self.xs.append(self.xval)  # or any arbitrary update to your figure's data
        else:
            self.xval += 0.005
            self.xs.append(self.xval)

    # Draw x and y lists
    self.ax.clear()
    self.ax.plot(self.xs, self.ys)

    # Format plot
    self.ax.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0,5,0.25))
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.30)
```

Comment: Seems you are using `draw` before you plot your data.

Comment: You need to decide if you want to show your figure inside a custom `FigureCanvasTkAgg` or if you want to use `pyplot`. Mixing both will not result in anything useful.

Comment: ...and inform people about your decision if further help is required.

Comment: So ideally i'd be using FigureCanvasTkAgg and scrapping the pyplot functionality. But based on the tutorials ive seen, it appears that pyplot is used to plot the data and then, FigureCanvasTkAgg is used to take the plotted figure and bring it into the GUI. I'm still not sure how that was possible.

Comment: The [tk example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html#sphx-glr-gallery-user-interfaces-embedding-in-tk-sgskip-py) on the matplotlib page does not use pyplot. Itll use `self.fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure()`. (Note that if you want to notify someone you need to use the @username notation)